# IFRAME src different from the url actually loaded

Tags: iframe

This is my first question. There is an IFRAME. When I checked the src, it showing some blank.html file. I am unable to read the controls from this. While I am using the F12 option, it was showing some error in a JSP file with the name. Accidently when I right clicked the ie window, this file name was available in the frequently opened files. But this url of the JSP file was not shown anywhere in the code. WHen I tried opening this url while having the original ie session, it is opening and I am able to read the controls.

Is it possible to read the controls on the same frame, without opening in another window. How to read the url opened in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you could also paste your code.
Nevertheless check this.

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="demo.html" onload="doSomething()"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('ifrm').onload = function() {
// put your code here
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Stark, but the website is not designed my me. It is my client site. I am trying to automate by reading the controls in iframe. I can't share the code due to security reasons. The src is different fro actual url loaded. It is showing access denied when I try to access content document of the iframe. If I use the document, it is showing the controls of the parent frame only.

Comment: I am afraid if anyone could help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the reason. For iframes, we need to use `iframe.contentwindow.document` instead of just `iframe.document`.